# Intent Filter for android.intent.action.CALL

Tags: android

I have an intent filter that looks like so:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.test.Call"
    android:label="@string/makeCall" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This works fine and when you try to make a call my text appears as one of the options.  What I want to do is process the number being called and ask the user some questions and then continue on with the call.  I do this by running the following code after I do whatever processing I have do do:

```
Uri phoneCall = Uri.parse("tel:"  + numToCall);
Intent caller = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, phoneCall);
startActivity(caller);
```

The issue is, it is displaying the same options from the beginning again (the native caller and my intent filter).  This is not what I want, I want to bypass my intent filter and go directly to the native caller.  Is there a way to do this?  How can I force the intent to go directly to the native caller?  I am looking at moving this to a broadcast receiver but would rather go this route.

Thanks

Comment: What I can say is to start the Dialer activity explicitly, instead of start the intent with ACTION_DIAL, however, it seems that every phone manufacturer has their own Dialer, so it would be a little difficulty to cover all brands. Like: `caller.setClass(this,dial_activity.class);` Now the system will ignore any intent filters.

Comment: Actually, I think it is the ACTION_CALL class that I want.  That was a typo in my original question.  Regardless, this is what I was considering, explicitly setting the class I want.  The thing is, I don't know how to find this out.  I have looked through the API but I can't find it.  How would I find this out?

Comment: Hi, I am adding same intent filter in my activity but not able to receive tel:number intent

Comment: Can you please help

Comment: Hey, sorry I have not worked on Android apps in years.  I never got around to trying to get this to work as I got busy with work and moved on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try disabling your component via PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting() [use the DONT_KILL_APP flags!], but you'll need to re-enable the component again before the next call.

Or you could take Huang's comment above but find out components that catch the ACTION_CALL intent and build your own chooser if there's more than one other than you - use PackageManager.queryIntentActivities() to get a list of Activities.

Using the broadcast is really the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am going to give both of those a try, I kinda gave up on this one.  I wanted to try both those solutions but didn't know how to disable my component or how to find out the activity that handles the calling.