# How do i make an app show up in disambiguation dialogue

Tags: android, intentfilter

Im making a phone app, i read that in order to make my app appear as an alternative when the disambiguation dialogue shows up asking "Call via..." i had to make an intent filter like this:

```
<activity
            android:name="..."
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="Simplifi lines">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

                <data android:scheme="tel"/>
                <data android:scheme="sip"/>
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

However this does not make my app appear as an option whenever i click a phone number hyperlink.

What should i do in order to get this to work?

ps: i tried to find for a question already answered about this but couldn't find much [Intent Filter for android.intent.action.CALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003881/intent-filter-for-android-intent-action-call).

Comment: Did you ask the permission for making phone calls?

Comment: Sure did, tried granting all permissions asked and then restarting but didn't work.